# Calling Microsoft graph function in typescript/react to verify owners of M365 group

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm new to React and TypeScript. I would like to call Microsoft Graph API to check if the logged in user is an owner of a M365 group via my React/TypeScript application.

I have this code:

```
import { callMsGraph } from "../utils/MsGraphApiCall";

function VerifyOwner() {
  const [owner, setOwner] = useState([]);
  const [err, setError] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    callMsGraph()
      .then(response => setOwner(response))
      .catch(err => setError(err));
  }, [])  

  return (    
      <div>
        {owner}
      </div>
  );
}
```

MsGraphApiCall.ts

```
export async function callMsGraph() {
    const account = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
    if (!account) {
        throw Error("No active account! Verify a user has been signed in and setActiveAccount has been called.");
    }

    const response = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
        ...loginRequest,
        account: account
    });

    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`;
    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    return fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group-id>/members?$count=true", options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Is there an API to check the owners of a group? In the above code, I'm getting all the members from the group.

I receive the error that **{"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2023-04-17T22:29:14","request-id":"f337f9cf-742a-41cd-a939-65bab6157942","client-request-id":"f337f9cf-742a-41cd-a939-65bab6157942"}}}**. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one M365 group having one user and service principal as **owners** like below:

[image]

To check the **owners** of the group, you can make use of below Graph API query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupID>/owners
```

**Response:**

[image]

> **Note:** If you are using `v1.0` Graph API endpoint, you will get only owners of **user** type in response.

To get owners of group with **service principal** type, you can make use of below Graph API query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupID>/owners/microsoft.graph.servicePrincipal/
```

**Response:**
[image]

> The error **"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"**
> usually occurs if your application don't have required `API permissions` to perform the operation.

To resolve it, make sure to grant  **`GroupMember.Read.All`** or **`Group.Read.All`**  API permission of **Delegated** type in your application as you are using **Delegated** flow to get access token:

[image]

In your `MsGraphApiCall.ts` file, change **graph API query** based on your requirement like below:

```js
export async function callMsGraph() {
    const account = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
    if (!account) {
        throw Error("No active account! Verify a user has been signed in and setActiveAccount has been called.");
    }

    const response = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
        ...loginRequest,
        account: account
    });

    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`;
    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    return fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group-id>/owners", options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```